# How to use production build of react/react-dom/etc on the server with webpack and ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babili

The official docs for React describe how to generate a production build with [webpack using UglifyJS plugin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#webpack) and how to validate that one really is using the production build in a browser. However, I'm using NodeJS 7.x (and hopefully will switch to 8.x soon) and I'm using Babel `preset-env`, because I don't want to compile ES6 features supported already by NodeJS (e.g. async/await) to ES5. Thus, I can't use UglifyJS plugin, because it doesn't work with ES6 code yet. I tried switching to Babili, but its default preset does some unsafe transformations (see https://github.com/babel/babili/issues/570) that cause my code to break. I can modify the preset to use only safe transformation, but the thing is that I'm not really interested in minifying the code, as it will be executed only on the server; I'm only interested in removing dead code that might eventually slow down the server.

So what's better? Is it better to use a minifier like Babili and configure it to only remove dead code using safe transformations, or maybe it's better to use Webpack `Resolve#alias` to load production build of React from `dist` folder?

Comment: Have you considered using the production build with create-react-app instead: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#create-react-app

Comment: Nope. We got our own webpack config for the client (with 3 mini apps) and server and I don't really want to switch now to a completely different solution. Though we might eventually switch to next.js in the future...

Comment: I just found that [next.js is using Resolve#alias](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/v3-beta/server/build/webpack.js#L310-L313), so maybe it's not such a bad idea. However, I can't figure out how it works, because they alias `react-dom` as `react-dom.min.js`, but then require `react-dom/server`...